# Materialize datepicker no funciona en ipad

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, materialize

Hola hace desde hace poco tiempo eh comenzado a utilizar materialize para un proyecto, hace tiempo me di cuenta que los `input` `select` no funcionan bien en ipad ya que al seleccionar uno se selecciona uno o dos depués del seleccionado esto se puede solucionar con el siguiente codigo

```
  $('li[id^="select-options"]').on('touchend', function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

ahora ya solucionado ese problema al hacer un datepicker me di cuenta que para seleccionar mes y año se utilizan dos `select` los cuales al seleccionar un mes o un año en ipad selecciona uno o dos posteriores (como con los otros `select`) y al intentar implementar el codigo de arriba para los `select` de fecha y año no funciona y no entiendo el por que dejo un fragmento de ambos `select`.

> este funciona

```
    <div class="select-wrapper">
  <input class="select-dropdown dropdown-trigger" type="text" readonly="true" data-target="select-options-ae606bcb-7192-b3a0-8acd-8466a294e6af">
  <ul id="select-options-ae606bcb-7192-b3a0-8acd-8466a294e6af" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" tabindex="0" style="display: block; width: 292.417px; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 600px; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; opacity: 1; transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1);">
    <li class="disabled selected" id="select-options-ae606bcb-7192-b3a0-8acd-8466a294e6af0" tabindex="0"><span>Escolaridad</span></li>
    <li id="select-options-ae606bcb-7192-b3a0-8acd-8466a294e6af1" tabindex="0"><span>Sin instrucción</span></li>
  </ul>
  <svg class="caret" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path></svg>
```

> este no

```
   <ul id="select-options-1a5d41f5-bd0f-30a9-c27c-6cd7652c66c4" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" tabindex="0" style="display: block; width: 113.05px; left: 1020px; top: 96.6px; height: 600px; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; opacity: 1; transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1);">
<li id="select-options-1a5d41f5-bd0f-30a9-c27c-6cd7652c66c40" tabindex="0"><span>Enero</span></li>
<li id="select-options-1a5d41f5-bd0f-30a9-c27c-6cd7652c66c41" tabindex="0" class="selected"><span>Febrero</span></li>
</ul>
```